# What is the r folder on the TFS build server

Tags: tfs, build, release

We use the build and release parts of TFS 2017. On the server we can see that there are some folders called r1, r2 etc. In the same folder are also the builds located with a number as folder name.

What is the r folder used for? Can we delete the folders without breaking anything inside TFS? Can we set a retension period for the folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are folders used when running a release to hold artifacts.

You can delete them, but the next time a release runs on that agent, the data will come back. There's no point in deleting them unless you're never running a particular release again. Think of them as reserved disk space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is any retention setting for the r folders?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, seems you are talking about  `C:\agent_work\r1\a` & `C:\agent_work\r2\a` It' called **Agent.ReleaseDirectory**

> The directory to which artifacts are downloaded during deployment of a
>   release. **The directory is cleared before every deployment if it
>   requires artifacts to be downloaded to the agent.** Same as
>   System.ArtifactsDirectory and System.DefaultWorkingDirectory.

You don't have to manually delete them, as you see above, the directory is cleared automatically if the new deployment requires artifacts to be downloaded to the agent.

More details info about this you could refer [Default variables of Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#default-variables) from official MSDN doc.